# How to fix java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe?

Tags: java, exception, post, sockets

I am using apache commons http client to call url using post method to post the parameters and it is throwing the below error rarely.

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity.writeRequest(ByteArrayRequestEntity.java:90)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
```

Can someone suggest what is causing this Exception and how to debug it?

Comment: this is best to try

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142409/write-an-inputstream-to-an-httpservletresponsev

Answer (score 113):

This is caused by:

- most usually, writing to a connection when the other end has already closed it;
- less usually, the peer closing the connection without reading all the data that is already pending at his end.

So in both cases you have a poorly defined or implemented application protocol.

There is a third reason which I will not document here but which involves the peer taking deliberate action to reset rather than properly close the connection.

Comment: I *have* confirmed the reason. You are writing while the other end has already closed the connection. The fix is not to do that. As the other end isn't reading it, there isn't any point anyway. As I also said, if this is happening there is something wrong with your application protocol specification or implementation, most probably that you don't even have one.

Comment: Thanks. Server side app has been implemented using HTTP protocol. It is running under tomcat. Am I doing any mistake in specifying headers? 

Also, Is it possible to identify whether the other end has already closed the connection in the client side code?

Comment: If the server side HTTP application is getting Broken Pipe exceptions it just means the client browser has exited/gone to another page/timed out/gone back in the history/whatever. Just forget about it.

Comment: In my case, it is happening in client side only.

Comment: So the *server* is closing the connection early. You're probably sending it something invalid.

Comment: We've seen this exception when aborting an ajax request in the browser (using `XMLHttpRequest.abort()`).

Comment: @obecker As I predicted on 23 February 2010.

Comment: One possible cause would be a proxy or Http server closing the connection too early. For example a Apache Http server between your J2EE server and the application clients, with a short defined timeout. At least that was what happened on our production environment. Clients complaint about pages not being fully loaded an we saw this errors on JBoss log. After some test we notice that the problem was a poorly configured Http Server.

Comment: @RicardoVila That's exactly what it already says in this answer.

Comment: This is a poor answer in that the OP asked for both "cause" and "how to debug"... In any case, cause it not necessarily (and arguably is rarely) related to "a poorly defined or implemented application protocol". As stated, it is because the listening (server) side of the socket will not "inform" the client the connection is closed and (such as in a case of a firewall) may not even know it is closed from client perspective. As for debugging, the way to know it is closed is by an attempted write and as for cause, must be traced through network socket chain (proxies et al) to Server.

Comment: @DarrelTeague 'Cause' and 'how to debug' are the same question, not two different questions. If it isn't an application protocol error, he *can't* fix it *or* debug it, unless he's on site sniffing the entire network when it happens, so all he can do in his code is understand what happened and take the necessary corrective action, which is to close the socket. Your own answer is eagerly awaited.

Comment: @shaoyihe No, it was because of the reasons stated in my answer. I don't know why you're even asking.

Answer (score 46):

In our case we experienced this while performing a load test on our app server.  The issue turned out that we need to add additional memory to our JVM because it was running out.  This resolved the issue.

Try increasing the memory available to the JVM and or monitor the memory usage when you get those errors.

Comment: I got the same issue during a load test. I guess the data takes a lot of time to be generated and the load testing tool does not wait the data long enough then it closes the connection. I your case, adding memory may have reduced the data generation process duration so the load test got all the data without the timeout limit. An alternative to increase the memory would have been to increase the load test tool timeout.

Comment: Clearly the low memory caused the application to close the receiving socket or indeed exit altogether, with the same effect. Low memory *by itself* doesn't cause broken pipes.

Comment: this actually appears to be an issue during our heavy-load application as well

Answer (score 12):

SocketException: Broken pipe, is caused by the 'other end' (The client or the server) closing the connection while your code is either reading from or writing to the connection.

This is a very common exception in client/server applications that receive traffic from clients or servers outside of the application control. For example, the client is a browser. If the browser makes an Ajax call, and/or the user simply closes the page or browser, then this can effectively kill all communication unexpectedly. Basically, you will see this error any time the other end terminates their application, and you were not anticipating it.

If you experience this Exception in your application, then it means you should check your code where the IO (Input/Output) occurs and wrap it with a try/catch block to catch this IOException. It is then, up to you to decide how you want to handle this semi-valid situation.

In your case, the earliest place where you still have control is the call to `HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry` - So ensure that call is wrapped with the try/catch block, and handle it how you see fit.

I would strongly advise against logging SocketException-Broken Pipe specific errors at anything other than debug/trace levels. Else, this can be used as a form of DOS (Denial Of Service) attack by filling up the logs. Try and harden and negative-test your application for this common scenario.

Comment: It is not caused by the peer closing the connection while you are reading from it. That causes a different, end of stream, condition, which is often not an exception at all.

Answer (score 8):

All the open streams & connections need to be properly closed, so the next time we try to use the urlConnection object, it does not throw an error. As an example, the following code change fixed the error for me.

Before:

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
bw.write("Some text");
bw.close();
out.close();
```

After:

```
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
bw.write("Some text");
bw.close();
out.close();
os.close(); // This is a must.
```

Comment: This is actually very strange, because a `BufferedOutputStream` always calls `close()` on its underlying output stream (thus on the output stream of `urlConnection`). See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close()
So when you call `os.close()` it should have been closed already. No?

Comment: 'os.close()' is not 'a must'. Neither is 'out.close()' for that matter. 'bw.close()' is sufficient. @obedker is correct. This change alone cannot have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd the same problem while I was developing a simple Java application that listens on a specific TCP. Usually, I had no problem, but when I run some stress test I noticed that some connection broke with error `socket write exception`.

After Investigation I found a solution that solves my problem. I know this question is quite old, but I prefer to share my solution, someone can find it useful.

The problem was on ServerSocket creation. I read from Javadoc there is a default limit of 50 pending sockets. If you try opening another connection, these will be refused. The solution consist simply in change this default configuration at server side. In the following case, I create a Socket server that listen at TCP port `10_000` and accept max `200` pending sockets.

```java
new Thread(() -> {
      try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10_000, 200)) {
        logger.info("Server starts listening on TCP port {}", port);

        while (true) {
          try {
            ClientHandler clientHandler = clientHandlerProvider.getObject(serverSocket.accept(), this);
            executor.execute(clientHandler::start);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
          }
        }

      } catch (IOException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error("Could not open server on TCP port {}. Reason: {}", port, e.getMessage());
      }
    }).start();
```

From Javadoc of [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html):

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a request to connect) is set to the backlog parameter. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full, the connection is refused.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with connection resets whatsoever. If you got as far as having a client socket to write to, you didn't encounter a listen backlog limit, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented data downloading functionality through FTP server and found the same exception there too while resuming that download.
To resolve this exception, you will always have to disconnect from the previous session and create new instance of the Client and new connection with the server. This same approach could be helpful for HTTPClient too.

Comment: To resolve this error you have to avoid trying to use closed sockets.

Comment: LOL. You could waste all day correcting all the bogus advice on SO.

Comment: @Dave Indeed. Sometimes I do.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers illustrate the reason for this `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe`: the other end closed the connection. I would like to share experience what happened when I encountered it:

1. in a client's request, the `Content-Type` header is mistakenly set larger than request body actually is (in fact there was no body at all)
2. the bottom service in tomcat socket was waiting for that sized body data (http is on TCP which ensures delivery by encapsulating and ...)
3. when 60 seconds expired, tomcat throws time out exception: 
   `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null`
4. client receives a response with status code 500 because of the timeout exception.
5. client close connection (because it receives response).
6. tomcat throws `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` because client closed it.

Sometimes, tomcat does not throw broken pip exception, because timeout exception close the connection, why such a difference is confusing me too.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header doesn't specify a number, so it cannot be 'larger' than anything. Timeout exceptions do not close the socket. Answer makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP maybe it was content length, don't remember. I think the timeout in Tomcat makes it return 500, while client receives this response and close the connection, which finally causes tomcat does not receive enough bytes as it expects.

Comment: If Tomcat sends 500 it has already received everything it plans to. Still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 not really. Tomcat sends 500 because it does not receive all it expects, but timed out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that your deployed files are not updated with the correct RMI methods. Check to see that your RMI interface has updated parameters, or updated data structures that your client does not have. Or that your RMI client has no parameters that differ from what your server version has.

This is just an educated guess. After re-deploying my server application's class files and re-testing, the problem of "Broken pipe" went away.

Comment: *What* RMI methods? RMI isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I was using the incorrect HTTP request url while making it, later which i changed that it resolved my problem. my upload url was : http://192.168.0.31:5000/uploader while i was using http://192.168.0.31:5000. that was a get call. and got a java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe? exception.

That was my reason. might lead you to check one more point when this issue

```
  public void postRequest()  {


        Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);

        System.out.println("mediafilename-->>" + mediaFileName);
        String[] dirarray = mediaFileName.split("/");
        String file_name = dirarray[6];
        //Thread.sleep(10000);

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("file",file_name, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), new File(mediaFileName))).build();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
//        ExecutorService executor = newFixedThreadPool(20);
//        Request request = new Request.Builder().post(requestBody).url("https://192.168.0.31:5000/uploader").build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.0.31:5000/uploader").post(requestBody).build();
//        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.0.31:5000").build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

//

                call.cancel();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong:" + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            System.out.println(response.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });


                System.out.println("Response ; " + response.body().toString());
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(response);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

> JavaDoc:
>
> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a
>   request to connect) is set to 50. If a connection indication arrives
>   when the queue is full, the connection is refused.

You should increase "backlog" parameter of your ServerSocket, for example

```
int backlogSize = 50 ;
new ServerSocket(port, backlogSize);
```

Comment: Increasing the backlog will not solve a 'broken pipe' error.

Comment: but it helped for me

Comment: @EJP I tested a server on Linux and it worked, but on Mac OS - not. And increasing backlog size helped me. I didn't know that max size is 50.

Comment: You tested something else. Listen backlog has nothing to do with this exception. It helps connection refusals or timeouts at the client. Not 'socket closed' exceptions, which are a local error.

Comment: For socket pools (such as an HTTP server like Tomcat) there are configuration settings for the number of pending "accepts" the server will "queue" before dispatching servicing threads and a separate setting for the number of threads in the pool. However, none of this is related to the issue that _after_ the Server "accept()" when the connection is established - the output stream is suddenly (unwittingly) "closed".