# java network-broken pipe and received file corrupted

Tags: java, network-programming, broken-pipe

I am trying to write a server that accepts files and write it in certain directory using DataInputStream and BufferedInputStream.

The server gets 'user name(string)' 'number of files(int)' 'file name(string)' 'size of each file(long)' and 'contents of file which is uninterpreted bytes(byte[])'

and if everything is successful then, I am supposed to send boolean value.

But the problem is that it is not receiving file correctly.

From time to time I get 'broken pipe' error message or the file is corrupted after I receive.

Fixed the problem..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2309561/851811)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small thing which may be related to your problem. You should be decrementing your file size variable by the number of bytes actually read, instead of the number of bytes requested to be read:

```
       while(fileSize>0){
            if(fileSize < byteSize)
                byteSize = (int)fileSize;
            int byteRead = din.read(b, 0, byteSize);
            fos.write(b);
            fileSize -= byteRead; // <-- See here
        }
```

Comment: +1 It's likely that this is the real issue behind the error. If reading less bytes than required, this can make the program exit the `while` loop prematurely and mis-get the next file length. This can lead to keeping reading the inputstream when there's no more data.

Comment: Also you should check the `byteRead` result and not write the whole buffer array to the output each time but only the amount of bytes actually read. Otherwise you might write sections of the read data to the output twice.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this error if when reading the input, the sender closes the connection. It probably has nothing to do with your code. The sender might have timed out, closed the connection before the transfer has finished, or many other things.

Take a look at this related question:  [How to fix java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309561/851811)