# Write an InputStream to an HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, inputstream, outputstream

I have an InputStream that I want written to a HttpServletResponse.
There's this approach, which takes too long due to the use of byte[]

```
InputStream is = getInputStream();
int contentLength = getContentLength();

byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
is.read(data);

//response here is the HttpServletResponse object
response.setContentLength(contentLength);
response.write(data);
```

I was wondering what could possibly be the best way to do it, in terms of speed and efficiency.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just write in blocks instead of copying it entirely into Java's memory first. The below basic example writes it in blocks of 10KB. This way you end up with a consistent memory usage of only 10KB instead of the complete content length. Also the enduser will start getting parts of the content much sooner.

```
response.setContentLength(getContentLength());
byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

try (
    InputStream input = getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
) {
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

---

As creme de la creme with regard to performance, you could use NIO [`Channels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html) and a directly allocated [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Create the following utility/helper method in some custom utility class, e.g. `Utils`:

```
public static long stream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try (
        ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(input);
        WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);
    ) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10240);
        long size = 0;

        while (inputChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();
            size += outputChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }

        return size;
    }
}
```

Which you then use as below:

```
response.setContentLength(getContentLength());
Utils.stream(getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Of course many utility packages have this method already defined, so once you start using Guava...  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: +1 @BalusC Do we need to set its ContentType? If yes, what would it be?

Comment: @Roylee: yes, that's recommended. Just set the content type to the type of the content :) http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: i tried this,, why is that my stream will return an error like this: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:778)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:707)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)

Comment: how to getContentLenght() of input Stream?

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedInputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
OutputStream os;
os = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
out = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
int j = -1;
while ((j = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, j);
}
```

Comment: I wan to avoid the usage of byte[], if possible

Comment: @MuhammadSabry there's no way to read the InputStream w/o using `byte[]`

Comment: What's wrong with byte[]. You need to store the data someware :}

Answer (score 0):

I think that is very close to the best way, but I would suggest the following change. Use a fixed size buffer(Say 20K) and then do the read/write in a loop.

For the loop do something like

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[20*1024];
outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
while(true) {
  int readSize=is.read(buffer);
  if(readSize==-1)
    break;
  outputStream.write(buffer,0,readSize);
}
```

ps: Your program will not always work as is, because read don't always fill up the entire array you give it.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by read doesn't fill up the entire array you give it?

Comment: Read does not always fill up the input array. So you need to check the value which read return which is the number of bytes read. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29)