# Embed PDF in webpage

Tags: spring, jsp, pdf

I tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp) by integrating it to the `Spring MVC` which result me to these codes:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/assign/{id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "id" )
int fileId, Model model, HttpServletResponse response )
{
    model.addAttribute( "id", fileId );
    File test = new File( "C:\\resource\\pdf\\Another Sample.pdf" );
    response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/pdf" );
    response.setHeader( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( test.length() ) );
    response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Another Sample.pdf\"" );
    try
    {
        Files.copy( test.toPath(), response.getOutputStream() );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:../assign.do";
}
```

JSP page:

```
<object data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Another Sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
     <p>Download Missing plug-in <a href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/" class="btn btn-link">here</a> </p>
</object>
```

But for some reason the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` causing an error:

[image]

I tried to click the link that accessing the controller it just displaying the PDF file in the whole page which is not my goal. **What I want to do is display the PDF in the object tag**

Comment: You need some kind of flash plugin or something for that. You can't normally display a PDF in one little portion of the browser screen.

Comment: I tried to display the PDF from one of the folder inside the project and its working. Are you sure that I need some flash plugin?

Comment: yes, you'll need a browser plugin, may not be flash, but a plugin is required. PDFs can't be directly viewed randomly in some area of your browser screen, they will instead be downloaded.

Comment: @coding_idiot From my point of view. The object tag already using the default plugin of the browser to view PDFs. As i said on my previous comment, I tried  to display a PDF file from the resource folder of my project and its working. My problem is when the source is outside the project, it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Sorry if it confused you, but `it just displaying the PDF file in the whole page` - not in a portion, because that's what the plugin does. To display in some small portion, you'll need some other plugin, something like [here](http://www.slideshare.net/)

Comment: @coding_idiot I see. Can you suggest a good tutorial or for newbie like me to follow? I'm really in a pinch now. I'm a week behind the dead line of my dead line.

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/

Comment: @CadisEtramaDiRaizel when the pdf is outside ethe project the ${pageContext.request.contextPath} will not work

Comment: Is there another way? of just using Spring and HTML?

Comment: @SarathSprakash Is there another way around without using plugin? With just Spring and HTML?

Comment: @CadisEtramaDiRaizel, if it is not of your project just directly give the path to that pdf

Comment: @SarathSprakash I tried to give it a full path like this C:/resource/pdf/Ang Kahalagahan ng Pamilya.pdf but nothing shows

Comment: @CadisEtramaDiRaizel you cannot access a local path using the html , if you paste the above path in browser , will you get the resource,

Comment: If you want to access local pdf file it has to be in your resource. html doesnot works on physical path , only on virtual path

Comment: @SarathSprakash this `file:///C:/resource/pdf/Ang Kahalagahan ng Pamilya.pdf` still doesn't work.

Comment: convert by using new File(path).toURI().toURL();

Comment: @SarathSprakash Wait I'm a bit confuse. If I do that then the Object type will be URI and the code will break.