# Hover on dynamic link generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a hover similar to the example [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) in the jQuery. But the link is **dynamically generated** so I'm really having a hard time figuring this out.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.g-tabs').on('hover', 'a', function() {
            $( this ).append( $('<i class="icon-clear-remove" onClick="tabRemove();"></i>') );
        },
        function() {
            $( this ).find( ".icon-clear-remove:last" ).remove();
    });
});
```

But its not working. Seems like my selector is the problem. How can I select it properly?

**UPDATE:**

This JS is handles for the view to not refresh if the tab is created:

```
$(document).on('submit','#pop-form', function(e) {
    // make an ajax request
    $.post('../admin/FLT_add_tab.do',
            $('#pop-form').serialize(),
            function( data ) {
                // if data from the database is empty string
                if( $.trim( data ).length != 0 ) {
                    // hide popover
                    $('#popover').popover('hide');
                    //append new tab and new tab content
                    var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length - 1;
                    $('#popover').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#tab_'+ id +'" data-toggle="tab" class="g-tabs">' + data + '</a></li>');         
                    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_' + id + '"> <c:import url="flt-pis.html"></c:import> </div>');
                } else {
                    // error handling later here
                }
            }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Not this one is the HTML that handles the tabs if the user goes to this page in first hand:

```
<!-- Other tabs from the database -->
<c:forEach var="tabNames" items="${ allTabs }">
     <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" class="g-tabs"> ${ tabNames.key }</a></li>
</c:forEach>

<!-- Add new tab -->
<li><a href="#" id="popover">New <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></li>
```

As requested the server side code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/FLT_add_tab", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String createNewTab( @RequestParam
String newTab, HttpServletRequest request )
{
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     String returnVal = Credentials.checkSession( session );

     if( returnVal != null )
     {
         return returnVal;
     }

     String tabName = null;
     try
     {
         DataSource dataSource = DatabaseCommunication.getInstance().getDataSource();
         QuestionnaireDAO qDAO = new QuestionnaireDAO( dataSource );

         if( qDAO.getTabName( 0, newTab ) == null )
         {
             qDAO.insertQtab( newTab );
                tabName = newTab;
         }
     }
     catch( Exception e )
     {
         // no logger yet
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return tabName;
}
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Can you make jsFidle example?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak It has no problem as `append` can take a parameter of `jquery object` see http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @newbie see [Jquery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/), I think that you do not use it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is dynamically created the you have to use the delegate

```
         $(document).on('mouseenter', 'a.g-tabs', function() {
                    $( this ).append( $('<i class="icon-clear-remove" onClick="tabRemove();"></i>') );
        });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'a.g-tabs', function() {
      $( this ).find( ".icon-clear-remove:last" ).remove();
 });
```

Comment: It should work perfectly, keep the above code outside of $(document).on('submit','#pop-form')

Comment: @newbie try this, I have updated the answer, its working for me. Hover is actually a combination of mouseenter and mouse leave, but you cant use hover as a delegate event, So you have to use both seperately

Comment: Is that suppose to be .remove()?

Comment: you just paste the above code instead of hover , and please repond

Comment: Its working if you replace the mouseleave with this `$(document).on('mouseleave', 'a.g-tabs', function() {
         $( this ).find( ".icon-clear-remove:last" ).remove();
  });`, please update your answer before I accept it.

Comment: @newbie updated, well i just checked the working of mouseover and mouseleave, not the contents

Comment: Can you help me with my one more problem. Its regarding with displaying PDFs? Please reply then I'll accept it regarding of what your answer.

Comment: Ok you can tell me,what is the problem with pdf?, Then my updated answer is correct only , you asked for hover issue I solved it,but I didn't code for what to do on mouseleave

Comment: This is my team mate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681933/embed-pdf-in-webpage?noredirect=1#comment29276755_19681933). Please help us and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS.

```
.g-tabs a>.icon-clear-remove
{
 display:none;
}
.g-tabs a:hover>.icon-clear-remove
{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

E > F   Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.
E:hover Matches E during user hovers E.

So, E:hover>F means that while user hovers E, apply rule to F.

Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/7bVTj/

Comment: I don't get it how can I use this. Sorry I'm new to web development. Including CSS. That is why I'm using bootstrap

Comment: paste this to your stylesheet css file, and instead of append and remove your <i> tag, just generate it with your server app, and append to every link. it will be hidden on document ready, and will be shown on hover even after DOM change.

Comment: I can't make it work because I have this in my CSS `.icon-clear-remove {
 background-image: url(../img/clear.png);
 background-position: center center;
}`

Comment: it should not interfere and should work. If not - teach materiel.

Comment: It seems the icon is not working if I replace my `.icon-clear-remove` to `.icon-clear-remove:before`. I don't know why the .png image doesn't show up.

Comment: You don't need `.icon-clear-remove:before`, it's just an example. will now edit and explain my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $('a.g-tabs').on({
    mouseenter:  function() {
        $( this ).append( $('<i class="icon-clear-remove" onClick="tabRemove();"></i>') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $( this ).find( ".icon-clear-remove:last" ).remove();
    }
}, "a");
```

this code from [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)