# Render PDF using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf

***This is the code I am using in my JSP to render PDF file***

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);

int b = 0;
while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) 
{
   out.write(b);
}
```

Path contains location of PDF file stored on local disk.
Problem: Its rendering stupid text. I could not even figure out what it is.

Any help is appreciated. What code to add/modify

Answer (score 0):

I think the very least you are going to need to set the response type to "application/pdf".  What is that out variable? If its' an HttpServletResponse, then you can do something like:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Many approaches for doing this are outlined here: [Displaying pdf in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp)

Comment: Actually the web page is divided into two divisions.
1 for displaying PDF and the other has a form which takes inputs
When I added response.setContentType("application/pdf"); to the code, web page is blank

Comment: So that code snippet above is embedded in the jsp or its' running server side in a servlet or a spring route handler or something?