# How to generate/prompt to download a pdf when user visit a jsp page?

Tags: jsp

I would like to let user download a pdf file (hidden location) after they agree a terms and condition. I don't want user download the file directly. (where the pdf file located at e.g. http://www.xxxx.com/download/abc.pdf)
or i should place the pdf file to https folder? if so, how to avoid user download it without accept a terms and condition?

Many thanks.
SC

Answer (score 0):

Change the header content type of a servlet and keep a logic to validate (token or something) inside that servet. You may reffer this post

[displaying-pdf-in-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp)