# Embedded PDF file not displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf

I am trying to render a PDF file in JSP file and used `<object>` HTML tag. It's displaying the PDF file in most of the browsers, but not in IE.

I searched on Google and found some posts which are suggesting me to use `<embed>` and `<iframe>` HTML tags. I have used those, but still no luck.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying pdf in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Well, any of the techniques should work, provided the browser knows how to display PDF (i.e. a viewer is registered) **and** `Content-Disposition` HTTP header of the file contains `inline` keyword (e.g. `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"`).