# How to display multiple Pdfs in jsp

Tags: jsp, pdf, servlets

I have a table in jsp with user information, where one of the columns represents user CVs:

First Name - Last Name - Cv

Tom        - bla       - file:///C:/CVs/Tombla.pdf

Jon        - b         - file:///C:/CVs/jonb.pdf

But, what happens is that both users end up showing the same pdf.

I'm trying to use the code in the following page:

[link] [Displaying pdf in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp)

````
<table id="users" class="display" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Cv</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <%
    List<User> users= findUsers();

   for(User user: users) {
 %>
<tr>
 <td><%= user.firstName() %></td>
 <td><%= user.lastName() %></td>
 <td>
   <object data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cv.pdf" type="application/pdf"/><% session.setAttribute("cv", user.getCV()); %>                             
 </td>
</tr>
<% 
} 
%>
</tbody>
</table>

```Webservlet

@WebServlet("/cv.pdf")
public class Cv extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String cv = session.getAttribute("cv").toString() + ".pdf";

    File file = new File(cv );
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"cv.pdf\"");
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
   }
}

Both users are having the same pdf displayed.

I think this is due to the fact that the variable for the session attribute is the same, but if i create a separate variable for each table line, how can I distinguish them in the webservlet code?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

If anyone is interested, here is what needs to be done:

JSP:

```
<object data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cv/<%= user.getCV()%>" type="application/pdf"/>
```

Webservlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/cv/*"})
public class CV extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException {
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString(); //gets full url address

if(url.split("/cv/").length == 2) {
    String cp = url.split("/cv/")[1] + ".pdf";

    //white spaces become %20, replace them
    File file = new File(cp.replace("%20", " ")); 
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", 
 getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"*.pdf\"");
    try {
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
  }
 }
}
```