# SocketException Broken pipe in Solr/tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, socketexception, solr4

I'm using Solr 4.3 with tomcat7. When the number of concurrent writes and reads increase it is crash throwing this SocketException error. I do concurrent commits and searches through multiple clients. Any kind of help is appreciated. Here is the tomcat log(catalina.out) and solr.log

```
 tomcat log(catalina.out):

    59887611 [http-bio-8080-exec-988] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – null:ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:406)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:342)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:431)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:419)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
     at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:141)
     at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:126)
     at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.startTag(XMLWriter.java:144)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writePrim(XMLWriter.java:347)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeLong(XMLWriter.java:305)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:139)
     at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.write(TrieField.java:221)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:130)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeSolrDocument(XMLWriter.java:199)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeDocuments(TextResponseWriter.java:275)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:172)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeResponse(XMLWriter.java:111)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLResponseWriter.write(XMLResponseWriter.java:39)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:644)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:372)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
     at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:517)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:401)
     ... 39 more


         solr.log:



    2013-09-19 05:32:13.978; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:406)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:342)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:431)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:419)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
     at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:141)
     at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:126)
     at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.startTag(XMLWriter.java:144)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writePrim(XMLWriter.java:347)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeLong(XMLWriter.java:305)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:139)
     at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.write(TrieField.java:221)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:130)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeSolrDocument(XMLWriter.java:199)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeDocuments(TextResponseWriter.java:275)
     at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:172)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeResponse(XMLWriter.java:111)
     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLResponseWriter.write(XMLResponseWriter.java:39)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:644)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:372)
     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Me...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more low level error. I found this [question&answers in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309561/how-to-fix-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe) and the summary of the solutions is to verify if you are really closing all the sockets (it would be indirectly due the framework) and check if it doesn't have other exceptions swallowed (like it needs more memory).

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with you closing all your own sockets or memory leaks, and if that's what you read from your cited question you've misread it.

Answer (score 0):

The peer has closed the connection. For example, the browser tab has been closed, or has navigated away to another page. There is nothing you can or need to do about it at your end. You can't write any more response, so stop trying.