# The cause of this output exception was that: ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I recently moved a site from Railo to ColdFusion 10 and everything went fine except one error that keeps popping up that i never got on Railo.

I have a page for downloading .pdf documents done with just a simple cfheader and cfcontent to deliver the files

The error i keep getting emailed is;

The cause of this output exception was that: ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe.

There was a previous question here;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301173/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe-while-using-cfcontenquestion

Unfortunately it is unanswered.

I can recreate the error by starting a download, and then cancelling it before its complete. So i thought maybe its just people cancelling downloads. But whats confusing me though is sometimes i'll get a few errors in a row, less than a minute between them, from the same user trying to download the same file, so i'm thinking is there any other reason for this error other than someone cancelling the download?

Comment: Related perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309561/how-to-fix-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe (There are several answers there, among them memory, which this sounds very much like)

Comment: "I recently moved a site from Railo to ColdFusion". Blimey. That's a first. *Why*? (also researching for a more helpful answer, but I am just so gobsmacked that someone would downgrade from Railo to CF I had to... comment... ;-)

Comment: Is it a possibility that it's just a case of normal client disconnects (ie: browsing away from the page before the file's finished transmitting), and Railo didn't report this as a problem (because it's not), and CF does, so it seems like it's a new issue? Anyone reporting any problems? I also agree with @cfqueryparam... do some memory profiling too.

Comment: Thanks cfqueryparam, i will look into the memory issue. Just as a little test, i set off a number of downloads at the same time for 60-70mb files, but it was fine.

Comment: Adam, we had a problem with collections on our hosts Railo server that they have so far been unable to fix, so we moved this one site to their ColdFusion server. I prefer Railo now though, even just for the admin on shared hosting, plus you know - i didn't get this error before! Regarding this error, it might just be ( and i'm hoping it is ) people just cancelling downloads/moving on like you say, but why would someone start and cancel the same download twice in a row? No ones reported anything.

Comment: @user3684025 When you reply to someone, if it's not the author of the question or answer that you're replying too, you need to use `@username`. Thankfully, there's a nice autocomplete, like when I typed @u, the autocomplete suggested the rest of your name, though you can only tag one person with this method. You were the first, so you're notified, but @AdamCameron isn't notified. Though he would be if I'd tagged him first.